# Wrapping MongoDB with a REST interface

Tags: c#, mongodb, rest, mongodb-query

I'm currently using MongoDB as my database, and I want to introduce an intermediate layer (REST interface) to make my application more flexible (See figure below) and to hide implementation details. My application is developed in C#, and I'm currently using the MongoDB C# Driver to create the queries, is there a way to instead of using `.ToList`, forward the stream of data from Mongo to the client when a query is executed? I do not want to build the whole result on the server and afterward sent it over to the client.

Looking forward to hearing your ideas :)

```
| ----------------------|
| Server:               |
| |------------------|  |
| |      MongoDB     |  |
| |------------------|  |
|          ʌ            |
|          |            |
| |------------------|  |
| |  REST Interface  |  |
| |------------------|  |
|          ʌ            |
| ---------|------------|
           |
  |------------------|
  |      Client      |
  |------------------|
```

Comment: REST interfaces return JSON or XML.  I suppose you could return a list of keys, but you have to return a chunk of static text for each RESTful call that returns any value, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: It doesn't have to - it can easily return binary data in a chunked fashion :) You do not believe it is possible to forward the result stream from Mongo?